# Gmail IMAP: Is there a way to get which mailbox is currently selected?

Tags: gmail, imap, gmail-imap

Are there any IMAP command or IMAP response code for Gmail IMAP, which can tell what is  currently selected mailbox?

We need this for debugging purposes and optimization.

EDIT: Why? We believe that 3rd-party library we are using will sometime not send "SELECT" command to IMAP server. So we need a way to verify what IMAP server things it is selected mailbox.

Comment: You need the mailbox to connect to imap so why don't you know which is in use ? Can you provide more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no IMAP command to get this information.

The best I can come up with is having a message in each mailbox saying which mailbox it is in and then you could grab the content of the messages to verify which mailbox is currently selected.